# Vim Airline interpreting .h files as cpp, not c

Tags: c, vim, neovim, vim-airline

Whenever I create a `.h` file, Airline interprets it as a `cpp` file (in the filetype section). How do I set it to `c`?

I couldn't find an answer online, and I don't know in where to change the source code of Airline to do what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filetype is set by standard Vim ftplugin. To change the default

```
let g:c_syntax_for_h = 1
```

See `:h c.vim` for more options.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the line to the vimrc

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.h set filetype=c
```

Comment: Thank you! @Matt provided a cleaner solution but thank you anyways.

Comment: @skevelis not at all))